# Export instruments trace data via command-line for leaks

Tags: ios, testing, instruments, memory-leaks

I am using the following script to run leaks instruments from the command-line.

```
instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Leaks.tracetemplate <app path>
```

after executing the command, i get instrumentscli0.trace file. How can i get readable data about leaks from that file.

Is there any way to export the results to a text file via any command. In automation template we can specify an output folder using the switch `-e UIARESULTSPATH`.

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/2210287)

Answer (score -1):

you can click "instrument > export data" in the menu to export the recent result to a .csv file. but i don't know how to do it with command line