# Is there a command line to export .trace of the mac Instruments?

Tags: ios, macos, instruments

I would like to export as CSV the .trace data (collected with Instruments) from the command line. Is there any command to run by shell? I'm looking for a command like that available in the Instruments GUI.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109217/export-instruments-trace-data-via-command-line-for-leaks)

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/2210287)